# list of directories into comma separated directories

Tags: sed, scp

Hi I am trying to do `scp` copy of directories from one environment to another environment. Suppose directories at location `\` as `dir1` `dir2` `dir3` and so on. Now as the `scp` copy I need to list these as `{'dir1','dir2',...}`. I am able produce quote (`''`) but not comma (`,`). Could you please help on producing comma? 
At the moment I can only produce `{'dir1' 'dir2'...}`. Not able to produce comma. Please help on this.

scp -rp hdqamktg@hdstg-c01-edge-03:/hdfs/app/qa/MarketingIT/warehouse/mktg_bdo.db/mktg_contact_roles_comp /hdfs/app/dev/MarketingIt/warehouse/hddvmktg/mktg_bdo.db/

(directories under /hdfs/app/qa/MarketingIT/warehouse/mktg_bdo.db/mktg_contact_roles_comp are
viewdate=2015-01-02 viewdate=2015-01-02 viewdate=2015-01-03 and so on)

It works with this: 
scp -rp $sourceUser@$sourceHost:$srcDir$pathSeperator{'dir1','dir2'} $targetPath$pathSeperator

the output that I am getting with the script is as; 
Copying data files for table "mktg_mbd.web_data_uri_sessionized" ...
{'viewdate=2016-04-02' 'viewdate=2016-04-03}

It needs to be {'viewdate=2016-04-02','viewdate=2016-04-03} for successful copy.

At target directory it has: viewdate=2016-03-01  viewdate=2016-03-05  viewdate=2016-03-09  viewdate=2016-03-13  viewdate=2016-03-17  and so on

```
END_DATE_COMP=$(date -d $END_DATE +%s)
                            NEXT_DATE=$ST_DATE;
                            NEXT_DATE_COMP=$(date -d $NEXT_DATE +%s)
                            DATE_LIST='{'
                            while [ $NEXT_DATE_COMP -le $END_DATE_COMP ]
                            do
                                      DATE_LIST=$DATE_LIST"'viewdate="$NEXT_DATE"'"
                                    NEXT_DATE=`date +%Y-%m-%d -d "$NEXT_DATE + 1 day"`
                                    NEXT_DATE_COMP=$(date -d $NEXT_DATE +%s)
                            done
                             DATE_LIST=$DATE_LIST | sed -i 's+ +,+g'
                            DATE_LIST=$(echo -n $DATE_LIST | head -c -1)
                            DATE_LIST=$DATE_LIST"}"
                            echo $DATE_LIST
                            #scp -rp $sourceUser@$sourceHost:$srcDir$pathSeperator$DATE_LIST $targetPath$pathSeperator
                            echo "copied the data for the partition viewdate="$DATE_LIST
```

As a result the date dir list comes as {'dir1' 'dir2'}. So I am missing the comma.

Comment: You mean, you dont have a comma in your keyboard?

Comment: no, are you kidding me? I mean these are the directories in location. In order to do scp copy. As the command these are needed to be with comma separated such as; scp -rp sourcePath/{'dir1','dir2',...} destinationPath. So i need to separate these with commas.

Comment: tried with sed 's/ /,/g' and  passing comma and so on. Not able to get the comma. @arzyfex

Comment: @rawal : I mean to say which sed command you used to add (") in it ?

Comment: i used directories followed with pipe and sed 's/ /,/g' (or dir1 | sed 's/ /,/g'). @arzyfex

Comment: you know you can `scp sourcePath/dir1 sourcePath/dir2 ... user@remoteHost:Dest` ?

Comment: @rawal : what have you used to get the quotes around dir1 and dir2 so on, So that I can modify your command.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us an example of your directory structure and the command you have so far. Do your directory names contain spaces or other special characters?

Comment: @Archemar Yes, it can be done that way too but I am approaching the other way. You can follow my script.

Comment: @terdon done editing. Please let me know if any idea.

Comment: @rawal you need to show us an example of your directory structure. Just run `ls` and add the result to your question. Then, show us the exact output you want to see from the example directory.

Comment: @terdon just updated. Please let me know if any questions.

Comment: @rawal please read [formatting tools](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) and format your commands as code. It's impossible to understand what you're doing there. And show us the output of `ls` in the target directory.

Comment: @terdon I have added the target directory contain, Sir. I don't see formatting option for the unix scripts. I am trying to list the source directories in scp command but not able to produce comma. Although with same approach works on the other simple test script.

Comment: Any line starting with at least 4 spaces is shown as code. That way, we can see what you mean better. All we need is `ls directory` to see the contents of your directory and an example of what you want to do with it.

Comment: it actually worked that way! @Archemar . Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there are no spaces in the dir names:

```
echo foo bar baz | sed "s#[^ ]*#'&'#g;s/ /,/g;s/.*/{&}/"
```

outputs:

> {'foo','bar','baz'}